# Is it possible to get the color of a particular pixel on the screen with it's X and Y coordinates?

Tags: python, windows, pixel

I would like to get the color of a particular pixel in Python using its X Y coordinates, is this possible?

This is in Windows, if it makes a difference.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this information?

Comment: Have you done that using win32? You will have to use win32 bindings for using the same API.

Comment: Karl, I'm going to make pseudo-shaped window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel under the heading for python

they give:

```
def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    import win32gui
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)

print get_pixel_colour(0, 0)
```

which uses [Python Extensions for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) which is available for python 2.3 to 3.1 at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/