# how to find the color of the button on wpf application using pywinauto tool?

Tags: python, wpf, pywin32, pywinauto

How to find the color of the button on wpf application using [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) tool?

Currently I am using pywinauto 0.6.3 for automating WPF *application*.

Comment: Has the answer helped to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Pywinauto does not support that, but you can get screen coordinates of element using rectangle() function and middle point using mid_point() (But in some cases in middle can be text). How to get color of some particular pixel [you can check there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331573/is-it-possible-to-get-the-color-of-a-particular-pixel-on-the-screen-with-its-x)

For example:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

def get_pixel_colour(point):
    import win32gui
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, point.x, point.y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)

dlg = Desktop(backend="win32").window(title_re='YourAppTitle')
bt = dlg.Button
bt.set_focus()
print(get_pixel_colour(bt.rectangle().mid_point()))
```